# how to use a numeric variable as character in plot_ly r graphs

Tags: r, graph, plotly

I am quite new to plotly so this is probably a basic question, I have a simple data frame :

```
id = c("01","02","03","04","05")
value = c(1:5)
data=data.frame(id,value)
```

When I plot it using plot_ly :

```
require(plotly)
plot_ly(data,x=id,y=value)
```

plot_ly think my id variable is a numeric variable, so on the x axis, I get graduation 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 ... which makes no sense.

If I want that plot_ly understand my variable is a character, I have to add some non-numeric character :

```
data$id = paste0("n",id)
plot_ly(data,x=id,y=value)
```

This code gives me what I want, but whith a disgracious "n" before my id.

Any ideas ?

Useless to say I have no problem using ggplot.

Comment: Works fine with the most recent version of plotly. The CRAN version is probably old. Try installing from github `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`

Comment: Did you try `plot_ly(data, x = as.character(data$id), y = value)`?

Comment: @royr2 : ok thanks, I will rather wait for the Cran package to update, not enough motivation to get source on github :).

Comment: @RaphaelK : yes I tried that but same result. Plot_ly seems to not care about the R format, but to re-estilmate if my variable is, up to it, character or numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/578) one needs to explicitly specify the axis type.

Hope this helps. Disregard my misinformed comment earlier.

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 y = 1:3)

# Works fine
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers")

# Treated as numeric    
df <- data.frame(x = c("1000", "2000", "3000"),
                 y = 1:3)

plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers")

# Force as a categorical axis
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers") %>% layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))


# Treated as categorical
df <- data.frame(x = c("1000A", "2000B", "3000C"),
                 y = 1:3)

plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers")
```