# Using Plotly To Create Heatmap w/ Numerical Rownames

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I am currently working with a dataset in which the rownames are all numerical values instead of characters.

Normally in `Plotly` it is quite simple to create a basic heatmap from such a dataset following the example of:

```
data <- as.matrix(mtcars)

plotly::plot_ly(x = colnames(data), y = rownames(data), z = data, type = "heatmap")
```

However it seems I am getting issues **because** the rownames for my dataset are numerical values. Any recommendations for how to resolve this?

Below is a reprex of my dataset:

```
set.seed(051939)
df <- data.frame(loci = sample(1000:5000, size = 50, replace = TRUE), a = runif(50), b = runif(50))
df <- tibble::column_to_rownames(df, "loci")
data <- as.matrix(df)
```

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112582/how-to-use-a-numeric-variable-as-character-in-plot-ly-r-graphs .

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

`plot_ly(x = colnames(data), y = rownames(as.character(data)), z = data, type = "heatmap") %>% plotly::layout(p, yaxis = list(title = "loci", ticktext = sample(1000:5000, size = 50, replace = TRUE), tickvals = 1:50))`

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

Solution found due to to @Viktor Horvath:

```r
plot_ly(x = colnames(data), y = rownames(data), z = data, type = "heatmap", 
    mode = "markers") %>% 
    plotly::layout(yaxis = list(title = "loci", type = "category))
```